# Sql query to print values starting from column A till column B

Tags: sql, oracle

New to SQL so looking for help

I'm trying to write a query which would print values starting from column A till the column B excluding the value present in column 'ANS' of second table.

Like here are the two tables X and Y

```
    Table1  
A   FROM  TO
a   6     9
b   3     6
c   0     3
d   2     3

    Table2  
A   ANS 
a   7   
b   5   
c   1
```

And I want the output as

```
A   ANS
a   6
a   8
a   9
b   3
b   4
b   6
c   0
c   2
c   3
d   2
d   3
```

I've tried to write something like this but it doesn't work

```
WITH y(n) AS 
(SELECT 1 AS n
FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT n + 1 AS n
FROM y, table1 T
WHERE n <= T.TO AND n>= T.FROM )
SELECT * FROM y;
```

Which prints 5000+ rows (that's why I am not attaching output)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Removed the MySQL tag since you are using CTEs.

Comment: I am using oracle..I added mysql tag coz I thought even they might be able to chip in some info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get all the numbers between from and to with a recursive cte, left join on the generated table and get only those numbers which don't exist in table2 using `not exists`.

```
--Get the maximum value of `to` column and generate all numbers between 0 and that value
WITH maxto(maxt) as (SELECT MAX(TO) FROM TABLE1)
,y(n) AS 
(SELECT 0 AS n FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT n + 1 AS n FROM y WHERE n < (SELECT maxt FROM maxto)) 
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT t1.a, y.n
 FROM y
 LEFT JOIN table1 t1 on y.n between t1.from and t1.to 
 WHERE t1.a IS NOT NULL) x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE x.a = a and x.n = ans)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

[`Sample demo`](http://rextester.com/KOWO13066)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH y(n) AS 
(SELECT level - 1 FROM dual connect by level <= select max(TO- FROM) +2 from table1)
SELECT t1.a, t1.from + y.n FROM table1 t1
         JOIN y on 1 = 1 
         left JOIN table2 on y.n + t1.FROM = t2.ANS and t2.a = t1.a
where y.n < t1.TO-t1.FROM  
  and t2.ANS is null;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for help..I tried your query and it gives almost correct result just that it doesn't print till the upper bound in 'TO' column, it shows till 1 less than TO value  ..something like [FROM, TO)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "hierarchical query" and a `MINUS` operation and avoid joins altogether. `MINUS` is easy to understand if you are somewhat familiar with set theory. Generating numbers using hierarchical queries is somewhat unnatural (and may only be available in Oracle, I don't know any other db products), but it is used very often and it works very fast.

I changed the column names to `from_n` and `to_n`; I don't remember if "from" and/or "to" are reserved words in Oracle, but why take the risk.

```
with
     table1 ( a, from_n, to_n ) as (
       select 'a', 6, 9 from dual union all
       select 'b', 3, 6 from dual union all
       select 'c', 0, 3 from dual union all
       select 'd', 2, 3 from dual
     ),
    table2 ( a, ans ) as (  
       select 'a', 7 from dual union all
       select 'b', 5 from dual union all
       select 'c', 1 from dual
     )
-- everything above this point is for testing only and can be removed
-- solution (SQL query) begins below
select a, from_n + level - 1 as ans
  from table1
  connect by level <= 1 + to_n - from_n
      and prior a = a
      and prior sys_guid() is not null
minus
select a, ans 
  from table2
;
```

**Output**:

```
A        ANS
- ----------
a          6
a          8
a          9
b          3
b          4
b          6
c          0
c          2
c          3
d          2
d          3

 11 rows selected
```

Comment: Hi, I agree minus is easier to understand but if the number of rows is more than I think it will be difficult to use

Comment: ?? I don't understand, what do you mean by that?

Comment: This answer has my vote; it only has to go through table1 once. I think the OP's confusion lies in the subqueries used to generate the data for table1 and table1 - they obviously wouldn't need to create those subqueries, because they can just query the tables directly!

Comment: @Boneist - That's possible, that is why I started to add a note to that effect right in the code in most cases, but in this case the OP demonstrated she/he is familiar with factored subqueries. I will add that to the code though, since it may help other readers.

Comment: Sorry @mathguy my bad disregard that comment